# Get Text File data using in php

Tags: php, explode

I have one text file in directory. I want to get contents of that text file.

**in my text file**

```
student&class&mark&grade
```

I am trying to my code here.

```
$myfile = "data.txt" ;
$getdata = file($myfile) ;

print_r($getdata) ; // student&class&mark&grade  // working fine.
```

I'm trying to explode function

```
$arr = explode('&',$getdata);
print_r($arr); // not working
```

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Use `file_get_contents($myfile)` to get the content and you should specify the path with file name.

Comment: Why the R tag? Unless you're looking for a solution in R please remove the tag.

Comment: the file() returns array and not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file()` function return the data in array -  [file function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

`file_get_contents()` return the data in string form
Try `file_get_contents()` -  [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$myfile = "data.txt" ;
$getdata = file_get_contents($myfile) ;

$arr = explode('&',$getdata);
print_r($arr); // Will work
```

Answer (score 1):

[`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) returns an array of the lines of the file, so this is the main problem.  You will also find that `file()` will, by default, include a new line on the end of each line - which you probably don't want.

This code uses [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to process each line, using `explode()` on a line at a time, replacing the original line with the array.

```
$getdata = file($myfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
array_walk ( $getdata, function ( &$data ) { $data = explode("&", $data);});
print_r($getdata);
```

This outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => student
            [1] => class
            [2] => mark
            [3] => grade 
        )

)
```